# I am getting error C2059: syntax error: '}' for a do-while loop exercise with Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

I try to run this little test program and I get the above-mentioned error.  When I delete the last } and rebuild the project, I get Error

> error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{'.

Am I missing something?  I am using VS 2013. I feel the syntax is somehow wrong, hence the error being churned out. Thanks for your help.

```
#include "iostream"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const string password = "Hello";
    string input;

    do{
        cout << "Enter your password: " << flush;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == password){
            cout << "password accepted" << endl;
        }
        while (input != password);
        cout << "access denied" << endl;
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: A do-while loop usually looks like `do { ... } while (...);`. Yours looks like `do { ... while (...); ... }`

Comment: Your `do` does not have a matching `while`. You seem to know that this is supposed to be a `do-while` loop. But where is your `while` for your `do`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, a `do-while` loop is:

```
do
{
} while(...);
```

What you have is:

```
do
{
while(...);
}
```

I'm assuming you meant for the `while` to go after the last brace. Right now, it's acting as a different nested loop that doesn't do anything, and causing a syntax error because the `do` is missing the `while`.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I got it know. There was a } missing.  Thanks for your patience. I hope to come up with a better question next time